# Lattice Point Combinatorics Question

Tags: combinatorics

"100 people are arranged in a 10×10 square grid. Person 1 can see Person 2 if the line drawn between Person 1 and 2 passes through no other people. For example, a person standing at (0, 0) can see a person standing at (2, 1), but they can't see a person standing at (2, 0), since the person at (1, 0) is in the way of their line of sight. You must prove that there are no five people who can all see each other."

It's clear to me that there are at least four people that can see each other, if you just select a 2x2 rectangle of points. However, proving that another person cannot see all four of those people is where I fall apart.

I began by recognizing that two people can see if each other if the differences in their coordinates are coprime. For example, if a person is at (0, 2), and a person is at (1, 4), they can see each other since their difference (1, 2) is coprime. If a person was at (0,2) and another was at (2, 4), then they could not see each other as their difference (2, 2), is not coprime: there is a person at (1, 1) that blocks them

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm unsure how to proceed with this information in order to prove that no five people can all see each other. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: how are they arranged ? randomly ? or on the coordinates ? it appears they are placed at intersections

Comment: They are arranged on the intersections of the grid, and each TA is placed randomly although it doesn't really matter. All the question is asking is to prove that no five TAs are all in visual sight of one another (i.e, that they're not blocked by another TA).

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations that 99% of readers don't understand. My own interpretation : TA = Teaching Assistant ? But why Teacher Assistants more than filmmakers, fruitsellers, etc... ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an undergrad student so TA is an acronym used too often!! But yes, it means teacher's assistant. Whether it's a TA or a doctor or fruitseller or whatever doesn't matter. All that matters is if there's a clear line of sight between points. Hope this clarifies

Comment: Are all TAs the same height? If the TAs are of different heights, then it is possible to have 5 that can all see each with no obstructions.

Comment: Are we to assume the $121$ lattice points $(x,y)$ of all pairs with $x,y\in\{0,...,10\}$, of which, $100$ are occupied and $21$ are unoccupied? Please confirm. Also, please identify the source of the problem. Is it from a competition? If so, which one?

Comment: It's a 10x10 grid, so there are 100 lattice points. At each point there is a TA. There are no unoccupied points. Apologies if this was not clear. It is from a midterm review for a mathematical cs class from my University.

Answer (score 7):

Assume the $10{\times}10$ square is represented by the region
$$
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\le x\le 10+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\le y\le 10+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$
with $100$ people, one at each of the $100$ lattice points (points with integer coordinates) of the square.

For an arbitrary lattice point $(x,y)$ there are $4$ possibilities for
$$
(x\;\text{mod}\;2,y\;\text{mod}\;2)
$$
hence for any $5$ distinct lattice points of the square, there must be two of them, say $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$, such that
$$
(x\;\text{mod}\;2,y\;\text{mod}\;2)
=
(x'\;\text{mod}\;2,y'\;\text{mod}\;2)
$$
which implies that
$$
\Bigl(
\frac{x+x'}{2},\frac{y+y'}{2}
\Bigr)
$$
is a lattice point, and moreover, since the square is convex, it's a lattice point of the square.

It follows that the people at $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ can't see each other.

Comment: Note that this proof works for any convex grid of lattice points.